# Auto-deleting mySQL query cache?

Tags: mysql, caching, reset

I'm the owner of a web-game with a high-traffic database with a lot of queries.
I'm now optimizing the mySQL and tools like mysqltuner keep saying that I have insufficient query cache memory.

```
+-------------------------+-----------+  
| Variable_name           | Value     |  
+-------------------------+-----------+  
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 218       |  
| Qcache_free_memory      | 109155712 |  
| Qcache_hits             | 60955602  |  
| Qcache_inserts          | 38923475  |  
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 100051    |  
| Qcache_not_cached       | 10858099  |  
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 19384     |  
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 39134     |  
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

That's from about 1,5 day of running the server.
Ideally the lowmem_prunes would be 0 of course, but there are very much queries which are user-based. Like,

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='1';  
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='12';
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='12453';
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='122348';
```

As I have about 3000 different users a day logging in you will have many queries like this in the memory.

I know about the ON DEMAND rule, but I'm avoiding it because we have a lot of queries which I don't want to check all over.

Increasing the memory wouldn't be a fix either since we're having so many queries.

Then I came up with the idea to make a cronjob to automatically RESET the query cache when the lowmem_prunes is zero. (which will probably be once an hour)

**What's the best option?**
1. Automatically reset the query cache once an hour
2. Buy more RAM and increase the cache with 1GB for example (which has it's downsides... I rather not do that)
3. Specify per query which should be kept in cache in which not.
4. Just keep it like this.